# How to capture changed Select/UnSelected Checkbox Node in a TreeView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp Treeview which i made for my understanding. 
   I would like to capture all the check and uncheck checkboxes node user selects.

I have tried to use a button click event in which i check for a CheckNodes. But i would like to know how to get the UnSelected nodes before he click the Save Button.

As per code, 
This is the format of my treeview 
On Page Load only 3 nodes are checked.

What if the user unselects few node and presses the save button.

How do i know capture the information of checkbox selected/Unselect on postback.

[image]

User Action

1. Selects -- Head1Child1GrandChild1
2. Unselects -- Head1Child2 &&
                Head1Child3
3. Expected Result : Need to capture checkbox
     Selects -- Head1Child1 && Head1Child1GrandChild1 (Code in Save_Click)

   AND Also need to capture

   Unselects -- Head1Child2 &&
                  Head1Child3

The given treeview is just a prototype to understand the problem for me. Imagine if there is 1000 nodes and user selects some node and unselects the selected node . I just want to get those unselected and selected node only. Thats it.

[image]

---

Thank you for your time.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" ShowCheckBoxes="All" Showlines="true" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Save_Click" Text="Save" />
            <br />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>


    //CS Code
    //TreeView on a PageLoad. 
    //It will create TreeView with all Checkbox checked
    // If the user Unselects one check box how do i capture that in a event ? 



  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
              if(!IsPostback)
{
                TreeNode tNode1 = new TreeNode();
                tNode1.Text = "HeadNode1";
                tNode1.Value = "HeadNode1";

                TreeNode h1ChildNode1 = new TreeNode();
                h1ChildNode1.Text = "Head1Child1";
                tNode1.ChildNodes.Add(h1ChildNode1);

                TreeNode h1GrandChild1 = new TreeNode();
                h1GrandChild1.Text = "Head1Child1Grand1";
                h1ChildNode1.ChildNodes.Add(h1GrandChild1);

                TreeNode h1ChildNode2 = new TreeNode();
                h1ChildNode2.Text = "Head1Child2";
                tNode1.ChildNodes.Add(h1ChildNode2);

                TreeNode h1ChildNode3 = new TreeNode();
                h1ChildNode3.Text = "Head1Child3";
                tNode1.ChildNodes.Add(h1ChildNode3);
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tNode1);

                TreeNode tNode2 = new TreeNode();
                tNode2.Text = "HeadNode2";
                tNode2.Value = "HeadNode2";


                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tNode2);

                ServerSideChangeSelection(TreeView1, true);

            }

           protected TreeView ServerSideChangeSelection(TreeView t, bool check)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode tn in t.Nodes)
            {
                tn.Checked = false;
                if (tn.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (TreeNode childNd in tn.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        childNd.Checked = check;

                    }                    
                }
            }
            return t;
        }
}
```

//Save Button Click for CheckNodes. Missing UnSelect Nodes ??

```
            protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                List<string> checkNodes = new List<string>();
                List<string> unCheckNodes = new List<string>();


                foreach (var item in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
                {

                    checkNodes.Add(item.ToString());
                 }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will make some changes to your code:

Created a property like below:

```
public List<TreeNode> Nodes
{
    get
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Nodes"] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Nodes"] = new List<TreeNode>();
        }
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["Nodes"] as List<TreeNode>;
    }
    set
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Nodes"] = value;
    }
}
```

In your page_load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        TreeNode tNode1 = new TreeNode();
        tNode1.Text = "HeadNode1";
        tNode1.Value = "HeadNode1";

        TreeNode h1ChildNode1 = new TreeNode();
        h1ChildNode1.Text = "Head1Child1";
        tNode1.ChildNodes.Add(h1ChildNode1);

        TreeNode h1GrandChild1 = new TreeNode();
        h1GrandChild1.Text = "Head1Child1Grand1";
        h1ChildNode1.ChildNodes.Add(h1GrandChild1);

        TreeNode h1ChildNode2 = new TreeNode();
        h1ChildNode2.Text = "Head1Child2";
        tNode1.ChildNodes.Add(h1ChildNode2);

        TreeNode h1ChildNode3 = new TreeNode();
        h1ChildNode3.Text = "Head1Child3";
        tNode1.ChildNodes.Add(h1ChildNode3);
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tNode1);

        TreeNode tNode2 = new TreeNode();
        tNode2.Text = "HeadNode2";
        tNode2.Value = "HeadNode2";

        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tNode2);

        ServerSideChangeSelection(TreeView1, true);
        List<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();

        foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.Nodes)
        {
            nodes.Add(node);
            if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
                {
                    nodes.Add(childNode);
                }
            }
        }

        Nodes = nodes;
    }
}
```

**Save_Click**:

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<TreeNode> unCheckNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

    GetCheckUncheckTreeNodes(TreeView1.Nodes, ref unCheckNodes);
}

private void GetCheckUncheckTreeNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodeCollection, ref List<TreeNode> unCheckNodes)
{
    if (Nodes != null)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodeCollection)
        {
            if (!node.Checked && Nodes.Any(x => x.Text == node.Text && x.Checked != node.Checked))
                unCheckNodes.Add(node);

            if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                GetCheckUncheckTreeNodes(node.ChildNodes, ref unCheckNodes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Added if (!ispostback) in page_load and changed in save_click

Comment: I am sorry i cannot take this answer , i have re-framed my question again . Please have a look . Also the TreeView1.Nodes when you loop will only loop at the top node it is a hierarchical tree which you need to loop through its children and grandchildren . Imagine if there is 1000 nodes and user selects some node and unselects the selected node . I just want to get those unselected and selected node only. Thats it.

Comment: Can you please delete this answer the code above does not  capture unselected node

Comment: i do not think you got my question . I am just looking to capture those checkbox nodes which user has unselected. Please look at my screen shot in which the user unselected some checkbox , i only watch to catch that node.. i dont want checkboxes that where empty at pageload.

Comment: ok, so those nodes which user has changed from check to uncheck and viceversa?

Comment: The TreeNode Collection  that you are looping does not know what node or checkbox you selected in UI . Unless you set the Treeview and Refresh it . It will always have the value for the checkbox that you set during pageload. Hope it make sense

Comment: Yes exactly whatever user Changed from selected state to unselected those nodes .. thats all ..The idea is to capture those nodes and save it in DB. When pageload happens the Treeview Data bound will populate those checkbox based on the value from the DB.

Comment: Can you please verify what is Nodes ?  Is it a List<TreeNode> you have declare somewhere ? i only see where you have set it i.e Nodes = node. I don't see where you have declared it.

Comment: its declared as a Property. See List<TreeNode> Nodes

Comment: Thank you for being so patient with me . I cant say how much i appreciate this help. Cheers.